# In function `uv__signal_global_init': ... undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'

Tags: c++, libuv, linker-errors

I'm using libUV in my project and I'm getting the following error when I'm linking...

```
In function `uv__signal_global_init': ... undefined reference to `pthread_atfork'
```

The strange thing is, my project only fails to link on certain flavors of Linux, but works on MacOS and Windows.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 3):

After scouring the internet, I found the solution in an obscure post from Ben Noordhuis in a [Google group post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/libuv/_y1a0ZXH7dA).

**#tl;dr**

> Link with `-luv -ldl -lrt -pthread` (in that order or it'll break when 
>   `-W,--as-needed` is in effect.)